# Hiding unnecessary JSLint warnings in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, jslint

I am using JSLint in Sublime Text 2 just to help with writing code, however, it shows me so many pointless *warnings* (i.e. unneeded spaces and indentations) that I can't even see the actual errors (like missing parameters and undefined local variables).

Is there a way to have JSLint ignore some of these warnings or anything to help me with this?

Comment: Might i suggest... fixing the spacing problems? the warnings will then go away. You only have to do it once. Don't forget to setup the jslint options to match your project's tabbing technique. (2space, 4 space, 1 tab, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Package Settings</kbd> > <kbd>JSLint</kbd> and add `,"--white"` to the `"options"` setting, it'll get rid of all warnings related to "sloppy whitespace"

Comment: @user3704979 If this indeed fixed your problem, could you mark the answer as "correct"? Just click the checkmark on the left-hand side.